# Is this a good firewall to keep brute force atackers out?

Tags: iptables, firewall

I am wondering, is the script below a good firewall script to keep brute force attackers out off my desktop?

```
iptables -F
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -p all -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -p all -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

Anyone?

Comment: Why specifically brute force attackers? What vulnerable service are they attempting to bruteforce? This seems like a possible [XY Question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem): You might be trying to ask about basic good security habits instead.

Comment: Against bruteforce, there is `fail2ban`.

Comment: With a default OUTPUT policy of ACCEPT, you do not need `iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -p all -j ACCEPT`. If your ip address is static then okay, but if DHCP then you need to allow it in.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a "hardened" version of Ubuntu then look at Ubuntu Pro rather than try to do the job yourself.

> Ubuntu Pro is a security-hardened version of Ubuntu targeted at enterprise and corporate users who cannot compromise on stability. It is sold as a subscription, but it is free for non-commercial use on up to five computers.

[How to Geek Reference](https://www.howtogeek.com/902519/what-is-ubuntu-pro/?utm_campaign=HTG-202307191500&utm_source=HTG-NL-DN&utm_medium=newsletter)

[Ubuntu Reference](https://ubuntu.com/pricing/pro)